# Load video to youtube when node save

Tags: 7, files

I have search but not found so I need to ask.

I need a module that permit to my users to load a video into the node add form and this video need to be loaded into my youtube/vimeo page.

Is there? Please...

M.

Answer (score 1):

A combination of following modules would do what you want

1. [Media](http://drupal.org/project/media)

> The Media module provides an extensible framework for managing files
>   and multimedia assets, regardless of whether they are hosted on your
>   own site or a 3rd party site - it is commonly referred to as a 'file
>   browser to the internet'.
>
> Media is a drop-in replacement for the Drupal core upload field with a
>   unified User Interface where editors and administrators can upload,
>   manage, and reuse files and multimedia assets. Any files uploaded
>   before Media was enabled will automatically take advantage of the many
>   of the features it comes with.

1. [Media: YouTube](http://drupal.org/project/media_youtube)

> Media: Youtube integrates with the Media module to make Youtube videos
>   available as file entities.
>
> Users can add Youtube videos to their site in a file field or insert
>   them into a WYSIWYG area by pasting the video's URL into the media
>   browser web tab. Formatter options are available to customize the
>   Youtube player's appearance, show the video preview image, and enable
>   the Javascript API. The 2x branch is under active development and uses
>   the Youtube iframe embed that can serve HTML5 videos to mobile
>   devices.

1. [Media Mover](http://drupal.org/project/media_mover)

This is the module that would do what you have asked. I have highlighted the point you have asked

> Media Mover is a set of modules which allows website administrators to
>   easily create complex file conversion processes. The core of Media
>   Mover is the media_mover_api module which creates a set of rules
>   allowing multiple modules to interact with a file. Media Mover can
>   take a file emailed to an email account, turn a file attachment into
>   an FLV file, create a new node with the file data, and then save the
>   file on an external file storage system like Amazon's S3 all at once.
>   And that's just the start.
>
> What you can do The core set of Media Mover modules offers lots of
>   options for someone manipulating rich media.
>
> - get attachments from an email account
> - get attached files from nodes of a specified type
> - get files from previously harvested files
> - get files from CCK filefield and imagefield fields
> - get files from a FTP server, provide file tokens for user authentication as well
> - create a thumbnail from a video file with ffmpeg
> - transcode video files into web friendly (and other) formats
> - compress a file with zip
> - move a file to Amazon's S3 service
> - attach file back to node
> - save file and related data as a node
> - add a file to a CCK filefield or imagefield
> - **save a file to YouTube**

Comment: Unfortunately, Media Mover relies on another module to save a file to YouTube. That module hasn't been ported to Drupal 7 yet.

Answer (score 0):

There is another light weight module which does the same thing well.
https://www.drupal.org/project/youtube_uploader