# Youtube API module: Post videos to Youtube

Tags: 7, files

I need to upload videos of my site to [Youtube](http://www.youtube.com). From [Load video to youtube when node save](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/58134/load-video-to-youtube-when-node-save) a few modules are introduced that do this.

But I need to do this using an API. I mean I don't want to use the modules interface, I need to have a special interface which is a simple `checkbox` in the node page of a video to post the video, once a user checks the `checkbox`.

The [Youtube API](https://www.drupal.org/project/youtube_api) module seems to be the appropriate module to do this, But I really have no idea of how to use this module. Using the APIs I can use a simple `.php`  file, by calling it via AJAX, then post the video.

How can I do this? Is there any tutorial for [Youtube API](https://www.drupal.org/project/youtube_api) module?

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom module, in **mymodule.module** use [hook_node_update](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_update/7.x)

```
function mymodule_node_update($node) {

  if (isset($node->field_checkbox[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'])) { 
  // If field checkbox is set (not empty), then...

     // youtube api code goes here. 

  }

}
```

> The Youtube API module seems to be the appropriate module to do this,
>   But I really have no idea of how to use this module.

According to the [Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/documentation/) module project page:

> This module is an API module, meaning that it **in itself doesn't do
>   anything**

Therefore, all this module does is install libraries that you need in order to interact with the Youtube API, nothing more.

You need to read the Youtube API documentation from https://developers.google.com/youtube/documentation/
and learn how to code for youtube api.

Comment: I am exactly looking for the section  `// youtube api code goes here.`

Comment: Well then read the Youtube API documentation. Didn't you say `Using the APIs I can use a simple .php file` you can use php in **.module** file...